# Detect a new page was added in an infinity scroll

Tags: javascript, observable, lazy-loading, setinterval

I have an infinity scroll and I want to check when a new page is added to the DOM. Since I am a third party to the website I wanted to know which of the following methods is the best method performance wise in order to detect such change to the DOM:

1. setInterval
2. Mutation observer
3. Scroll event
4. Intersection observer

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fire an event, or call a function, when you add a new page to your dom?

Comment: Its not my DOM. I have no idea when a user or a new page is added. That's why I need a listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't describe with expert knowledge but let me tell you my opinion.
I think the best option is using the scroll event and check window height every time the site is scrolled

setInterval is not a good option I think because if you set delay with long term, it would be shown has late response time or if you set delay with short term, the function is called lots of times even not necessary

And I'm not familiar with Mutation observer and Intersection observer but I know that both of these need to point to an element that is observed. It's okay if you know which element you have to watch but you are a third party. you have to check every time when the site is updated.

but Scroll event is doesn't have to point to an element and it will be called to a minimum.

I think the best option is using the scroll event and check window height every time the site is scrolled

Comment: Scroll event happens every 1 MS if I remember correctly. I can adjust an interval to appear every 300 MS. So how can scroll be cheaper than an interval?

Comment: @DanielHollander well, setInterval would be cheaper if you adjust every 300ms.  if you  okay to have 300ms delay, use scroll event and interval same time is the best option I can think of. search JS Throttleing